# Preventing Open Redirect in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, security, redirect, express

I have a set of node services, one of which handles authentication.  All services redirect non-authenticated users to a login page on the auth service, either setting a property in the request body or a parameter in the address so that they can be redirected back to where they were after login.  e.g.

```
https://mydomain.com:1234/auth/login?referer=https://mydomain.com:1235/usefulService
```

After validating login, I do a `res.redirect(referer)`.

My question is, is there a simple way of checking that the open redirect isn't being abused?

```
https://mydomain.com:1234/auth/login?referer=http://www.evildoer.com/fake/usefulService
```

I only want users to be redirected to services that I control - these will all have the same ip / domain+subdomain, but will have different port numbers.

Comment: Get the `referer`, and use [`url.parse()`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) function to check the host.

Comment: @Ravi - that's about where I'd got to, I suppose I was hoping for a complete solution that deals with all the corner cases (such as working for full domain names or localhost, and all the other things I haven't yet thought of) for me.  Not a fan of wheel re-invention!